# Check One Date is falling Between Date Range-Linq query

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, lambda

i am storing Leave Information of an employee in database.From and To Date will be stored in DB.I want to block employee to apply leave,when it comes in  already applied leaves range.

Eg: Assume one Employee already Applied Leave between 01/01/2015 to 05/01/2015,

```
i)if user again try to apply leave for 04/01/2015 to 07/01/2015,then i  need to block that one.
ii)if user again try to apply leave for 05/01/2015 to 05/01/2015,then i  need to block that one.
```

How can i find it using a Linq query

Comment: Did you find any answer useful? Could you accept the best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2015, 01, 04);
var endDate = new DateTime(2015, 01, 07);
if (_context.AppliedLeaves.Any(x => 
     x.UserId == userId &&
     ((startDate >= x.StartDate && startDate <= x.EndDate) || 
      (endDate >= x.StartDate && endDate <= x.EndDate)))
{
    throw Exception("You cannot apply this period");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you can try as below

```
    return (from t1 in db.Employee where ( empid == t1.EmplyeeId &&
date1 >= t1.LeaveStart && date2 <= t1.LeaveEnd))
```

you can try as below,detailed answer

```
int cntleaves = (from values in dbcontext.User_master
                       where values.iUser_id == Userid &&
                               ((values.dtStart_date >= Startdate &&
                                values.dtEnd_date <= Enddate)
                                 ||
                                 (values.dtStart_date <= Startdate &&
                                values.dtEnd_date <= Enddate))
                       select values).ToList().Count();

        if (cntleaves > 0) {
            ViewBag.Message = "You have already applied for leaves !";            
        }
```

Comment: @vmb  i edited my answer with addition of another detailed LINQ query for you, please implement the same and let me know if any question

Comment: It's better to use `.Any()` instead of `.ToList().Count()`

Answer (score 1):

Another better approach is create an extension method to the DateTime class as:

```
public static bool Between(this DateTime input, DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    return (input > date1 && input < date2);
}
```

And then you can use this with linq predicate where clause.

> if ( leaves.Where( l => l.empId == empId &&
>   dateApplied.Between(l.from, l.to)).Any()) 
>    { ... error...  }

PS: It is just pseudo code for your direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM table WHERE user = @user AND (
@newStartDate BETWEEN appliedStartDate AND appliedEndDate

)
PRINT 'Can not apply'
ELSE PRINT 'Can apply'
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This post is related to the querying between two columns within range that might help some developers.

1st step: Get into list

**var Price = GetLoad().ToList();**

2nd step: your search items

**string code = "PLUS";**

**var Total_Squares = 101: //value need to be checked within integer range**

**DateTime Checkdate = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-10-03"); //value need to be checked within date**

Query1 to check the range of integers along with the string value

**var filteredCodeWithSquare = Price.Where(C => C.Code.StartsWith(code))**

**.FirstOrDefault(r => r.FromSquare <= Total_Squares && r.ToSquare >= Total_Squares);**
a
Query2 to check the range of date

**var daterange = Price.FirstOrDefault(d => d.FromIntall**

**<= Checkdate && d.ToInstall >= Checkdate);**