# Check range of dates in db using linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, operators

I have DB table of billboard capacity. for example, the table contains the billboard id, from date capacity till date ending (id=1, fromdate 4.11.17 todate 19.11.17) in the table there are some few rows for this billboard id (21.11.17 - 5.12.2017, 20.12.2017 - 20.12.2017). I want to make some query check to see if this billboard is available between 2 dates and I am not getting the right results. for example, i am checking for dates like 3.11.17 - 3.12.17 or 6.11.17 - 21.11.17. The results I am need is if the billboard available in the exact dates I query. any idea?

```
public static int CheckisMediaAvailable(cDataClassesDataContext db, 
    long bId, DateTime fromdate_date, DateTime todate_date)
{
    return (from check in db.BillboardCapacities
            where check.BillboardID == bId
            && check.AssociateGuid == UserAccountManager.AssociateGuid
            && Convert.ToDateTime(check.FromDate).Date >= fromdate_date
            && Convert.ToDateTime(check.ToDate).Date <= todate_date
            select check).Count();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check One Date is falling Between Date Range-Linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232325/check-one-date-is-falling-between-date-range-linq-query)

Comment: This example is not working well. I have a row with the dates between 5.11.2017 - 19.11.2017 if i make some query like check if the billboard is available from 4.11.2017 till 29.11.2017 this code response that the billboard is available (which is not.)

Comment: Do yourself a big favor and store the dates as date(time) in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your `<=` and  `>=` around? If you want to check if the billboard is available on fromdate_date, the stored data should be be earlier and the todate should be bigger then the date you checkt as todate:

```
*****************************************************
   #######################     -> ok

              **************
   ####################        -> not ok

**********************************
           ############################## -> not ok
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to check if 2 range dates overlap at any point, you need to check for 2 cases:

- **Case1**: The `FromDate` is inside the range from `fromdate_date` to `todate_date`; and,
- **Case2**: The `ToDate` is inside the range from `fromdate_date` to `todate_date`.

If any of these conditions is true, than there is an overlap.

Before the cases, the proof that if neither the conditions are met, than there's no overlap. Using the diagram of Patrick Artner:

```
                       fromdate_date f***********t todate_date
FromDate F#########T ToDate                                    F#########T
```

> Look how, here, neither the `FromDate`'s nor the `ToDate`'s are between `fromdate_date` and `todate_date`.

**Case1**

It doesn't matter if the billboard finishes before the `todate_date`, or after, as long it starts after (or at) the `fromdate_date` AND before (or at) the `todate_date`.

```
                                     f***********t
                                           F#########T
                                        F#####T
```

> You can feel that the `FromDate` is trapped inside `fromdate_date` and `todate_date`, and so it must overlap with them.

**Case2**

It doesn't matter if the billboard starts before the `fromdate_date`, or after, as long it finishes after (or at) the `fromdate_date` AND before (or at) the `todate_date`.

```
                                     f***********t
                                 F#########T
                                        F#####T
```

> Analogously, you can feel that the `ToDate` is trapped inside `fromdate_date` and `todate_date`, and so it must overlap with them.

So, your conditions about the dates must look like:

```
        ...
        && ((FromDate >= fromdate_date && FromDate <= todate_date)
            || ToDate >= fromdate_date && ToDate <= todate_date))
        select ...
```